# File separation in Python

Tags: python, file

```
with open('C:\Users\craig\Downloads\folder\test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    test = myfile.read().replace('', '')
```

test.txt is:

```
hugh:ted
mark:mike
ethan:jay
```

how would I get python to remove the : and everything past :?
For example, how would I remove :ted, :mike, :jay, without having to manually write it in the replace part?

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('C:\Users\craig\Downloads\folder\test.txt', inplace=True):
    if ':' in line:                         
        print line.replace(line[line.index(':'):], '')
```

Comment: I'd prefer `line.split(':')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code snippet.

```
import re
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("/home/dma3node/test.txt", inplace=1):
    line = re.sub(r"\:(.*)", "", line)
    print line
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code-only answer would be better with some context; for example if you explain what techniques you are using to solve the questioner's problem, then it will be more useful to them and to other readers looking for answers to similar problems.